# Interpreting Unicode from Terminal

Tags: python, unicode, terminal

I'm having issues reading Unicode text from the shell into Python. I have a test document with the following metadata atrribute:

```
kMDItemAuthors = (
    "To\U0304ny\U0308 Sta\U030ark"
)
```

I see this when I run `mdls -name kMDItemAuthors path/to/the/file`

I am attempting to get this data into usable form within a Python script. However, I cannot get the Unicode represented text into actual Unicode in Python.

Here's what I am currently doing:

```
import unicodedata
import subprocess
import os
os.environ['LANG'] = 'en_US.UTF-8'
cmd = 'mdls -name kMDItemAuthors path/to/the/file'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
u = unicode(stdout, 'utf8')
a = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', u)
```

Now, when I `print(a)`, I get the exact same string representation is above. I have tried normalizing with all of the options (`NFC`, `NFD`, `NFKC`, `NFKD`), all with the same result.

The weirder thing is, when I try this code:

```
print('To\U0304ny\U0308 Sta\U030ark')
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-7: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

So, when that sub-string is within the variable, there's no problem, but as a raw string, it creates an issue.

I had felt pretty strong in my understanding of Python and Unicode, but now the shell has broken me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I am running all this in Python 2.7.X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems here.

- Like all escape sequences, Python only interprets the `\U` sequence in *string literals* in your source code. If a file actually has a `\` followed by a `U` in it, Python isn't going to treat that as anything other than a `\` and a `U`, any more than it'll treat a `\` followed by an `n` as a newline. If you want to unescape them *manually*, you can, by using the `unicodeescape` codec. (But note that this will treat your file as ASCII, not UTF-8. If you actually have both UTF-8 *and* `\U` sequences, you will have to decode it as UTF8, then encode it with `unicodeescape`, then decode it back with `unicodeescape`.)
- A Python `\U` sequence requires 8 digits, not 4. If you only have 4, you have to use `\u`. So, whatever program generated this string, it can't be parsed with `unicodeescape`. You might be able to hack it into shape by some quick&dirty workaround like `s.replace(r'\U', r'\U0000')` or `s.replace('r\U', r'\u')`, or you may have to write a simple parser for it.
- In your test, you're trying to use `\U` escapes in a string literal. You can only do that in *Unicode* string literals, like `print(u'To\U0304ny\U0308 Sta\U030ark')`. (If you do that, of course, you'll get the previous error again.)

Also, since this appears to be a Mac, you probably shouldn't be doing `os.environ['LANG'] = 'en_US.UTF-8'`. If Python sees that it's on OS X, it assumes everything is UTF-8. Anything you do to try to force UTF-8 will probably do nothing, and could in theory confuse it so it *doesn't* notice it's on OS X. Unless you're trying to work around a driver program that intentionally sets the locale to "C" before calling your script, you're usually better off not doing this.

Comment: Thorough answer. Thank you. It was the `unicodeescape` codec that I couldn't find via my Googling. I also didn't realize the difference between `\U` and `\u`. I had forgotten to add that I have `from __future__ import unicode_literals` in my first line (I always do), which explains the `print()` call. Also, the environ set is done due to the odd running environment of the script.

Comment: @smargh: The last time I had to do the environ thing was when I was ssh'd into a Mac from a Sharp Zaurus… but as long as you understand what it means and know why you need it, it's not a problem, I just wanted to make sure you hadn't copied and pasted it from someone trying to fix a similar-looking but actually-different problem without understanding it, as many askers on SO seem to do…

Comment: @smargh: PS, I'm guessing the `\U` came out of some Apple code? IIRC, Cocoa likes to use `\U` with 4 digits for BMP characters, because ObjC (unlike C, C++, and Python) allows `\U` with 1-8 digits instead of exactly 8 (and `\u` with 1-4).

Comment: It was spit out of the Terminal when using `mdls`. And the environ setting comes from writing workflows for Alfred app in Python. All Python code is ran in an empty sandbox, so I needed to set it explicitly when running `subprocess`.

Comment: @smargh: Ah, right, didn't see that. OK, then it's CoreFoundation, not Cocoa, but… same difference. I'm pretty sure this is actually the long-deprecated NeXT plist format, which CF/Cocoa can still parse, so if you want to call that through ctypes or PyObjC or Apple's custom CF wrapper, I'll bet it takes care of the escapes for you too…

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the other answers just slightly more direct code example

```
>>> s="To\U0304ny\U0308 Sta\U030ark"
>>> s
'To\\U0304ny\\U0308 Sta\\U030ark'
>>> s.replace("\\U","\\u").decode("unicode-escape")
u'To\u0304ny\u0308 Sta\u030ark'
>>> print s.replace("\\U","\\u").decode("unicode-escape")
Tōnÿ Stårk
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example; very helpful. For others who come later, if you need to convert Unicode with characters and diacritics that are written using separate code points into single code point Unicode (e.g. “e” plus an acute accent modifier into “é”), you need to normalize using the `C` modifier, so `NFC` or `NFKC`. Thus, `unicodedata.normalize(s.replace('\\U', '\\u').decode('unicode-escape'), 'NFC')`

Answer (score 0):

`\U` is for characters outside the BMP, i.e. it takes 8 hex digits. For characters within the BMP use `\u`.

```
>>> print u'To\u0304ny\u0308 Sta\u030ark'
Tōnÿ Stårk

3>> print('To\u0304ny\u0308 Sta\u030ark')
Tōnÿ Stårk
```